# Gitlab-runner / Ansible : Config Root user on mariadb install

Tags: ansible, gitlab, mariadb, gitlab-ci-runner

I set up a pipeline to install a web server **with ansible**. My problem is installing mariadb. Specifically, changing the root password.

My runner connects via ssh to a VM with the gitlab-runner user.

But I have the impression that this user does not have the rights to configure mariadb

this is my playbook :

```
---
- name: Installation de package
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  vars_files:
   - /home/gitlab-runner/vault.yaml
   - ./variables.yml
  
  tasks:

    - name: Install MariaDB
      dnf:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
      with_items: 
        - mariadb-server
      tags: [mariadb]
      # dnf install mariadb-server

    - name: copy .my.cnf file with root password credentials
      template: 
        src: my.cnf.j2 
        dest: /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf 
        owner: root 
        group: root
        mode: 0644
      tags: [mariadb]
```

Can you help me  ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share errors ?

Comment: Root@localhost access denied

Comment: i think this role might help you out:
https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_percona_xtradb_cluster/tree/main, specifically https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_percona_xtradb_cluster/blob/main/tasks/root.yml